# Prevent ngOnChanges from firing after emitting event (Angular 2+)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular 2+, custom two-way databinding can be accomplished by using `@Input` and `@Output` parameters. So if I want a child component to communicate with a third party plugin, I could do it as follows:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() value: number;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

    ngOnInit() {
        // Create an event handler which updates the parent component with the new value
        // from the third party plugin.

        thirdPartyPlugin.onSomeEvent(newValue => {
            this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        // Update the third party plugin with the new value from the parent component

        thirdPartyPlugin.setValue(this.value);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<test-component [(value)]="value"></test-component>
```

After the third party plugin fires an event to notify us of a change, the child component updates the parent component by calling `this.valueChange.emit(newValue)`. The issue is that `ngOnChanges` then fires in the child component because the parent component's value has changed, which causes `thirdPartyPlugin.setValue(this.value)` to be called. But the plugin is already in the correct state, so this is a potentially unnecessary/expensive re-render.

So what I often do is create a flag property in my child component:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    ignoreModelChange = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        // Create an event handler which updates the parent component with the new value
        // from the third party plugin.

        thirdPartyPlugin.onSomeEvent(newValue => {
            // Set ignoreModelChange to true if ngChanges will fire, so that we avoid an
            // unnecessary (and potentially expensive) re-render.

            if (this.value === newValue) {
                return;
            }

            ignoreModelChange = true;

            this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (ignoreModelChange) {
            ignoreModelChange = false;

            return;
        }

        thirdPartyPlugin.setValue(this.value);
    }
}
```

But this feels like a hack.

In Angular 1, directives which took in a parameter using the `=` binding had the same exact issue. So instead, I would accomplish custom two-way databinding by requiring `ngModelController`, which did not cause a re-render after a model update:

```
// Update the parent model with the new value from the third party plugin. After the model
// is updated, $render will not fire, so we don't have to worry about a re-render.

thirdPartyPlugin.onSomeEvent(function (newValue) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
    });
});

// Update the third party plugin with the new value from the parent model. This will only
// fire if the parent scope changed the model (not when we call $setViewValue).

ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
    thirdPartyPlugin.setValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
};
```

This worked, but `ngModelController` really seems to be designed for form elements (it has built in validation, etc.). So it felt a bit odd to use it in custom directives which are not form elements.

**Question: Is there a best practice in Angular 2+ for implementing custom two-way databinding in a child component, which does not trigger `ngOnChanges` in the child component after updating the parent component using `EventEmitter`? Or should I integrate with `ngModel` just as I did in Angular 1, even if my child component is not a form element?**

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**: I checked out [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) suggested by @Maximus in the comments. It looks like the `detach` method on `ChangeDetectorRef` will prevent any bindings in the *template* from being updated, which could help with performance if that's your situation. But it does not prevent `ngOnChanges` from being called:

```
thirdPartyPlugin.onSomeEvent(newValue => {
    // ngOnChanges will still fire after calling emit

    this.changeDetectorRef.detach();
    this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
});
```

So far I haven't found a way to accomplish this using Angular's change detection (but I learned a lot in the process!).

I ended up trying this with `ngModel` and `ControlValueAccessor`. This seems to accomplish what I need since it behaves as `ngModelController` in Angular 1:

```
export class TestComponentUsingNgModel implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    value: number;

    // Angular will pass us this function to invoke when we change the model

    onChange = (fn: any) => { };

    ngOnInit() {
        thirdPartyPlugin.onSomeEvent(newValue => {
            this.value = newValue;

            // Tell Angular to update the parent component with the new value from the third
            // party plugin

            this.onChange(newValue);
        });
    }

    // Update the third party plugin with the new value from the parent component. This
    // will only fire if the parent component changed the model (not when we call
    // this.onChange).

    writeValue(newValue: number) {
        this.value = newValue;

        thirdPartyPlugin.setValue(this.value);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<test-component-using-ng-model [(ngModel)]="value"></test-component-using-ng-model>
```

But again, if the custom component is not a form element, using `ngModel` seems a bit odd.

Comment: [you might want to read that](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 7):

Also ran into this problem (or at least something very similar).

I ended up using hacky approach you discussed above but with a minor modification, I used setTimeout in order to reset state just in case.

(For me personally ngOnChanges was mainly problematic if using two-way binding, so the setTimeout prevents a hanging disableOnChanges if NOT using two-way binding).

```
changePage(newPage: number) {
    this.page = newPage;
    updateOtherUiVars();

    this.disableOnChanges = true;
    this.pageChange.emit(this.page);
    setTimeout(() => this.disableOnChanges = false, 0);     
}

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (this.disableOnChanges) {
        this.disableOnChanges = false;
        return;
    }

    updateOtherUiVars();
}
```

Comment: It seems like the `setTimeout` would also prevent a problem in two-way databinding, if `this.pageChange.emit(this.page)` emits the same page number that the parent already has (in which case `ngOnChanges` wouldn't run). Basically a different way of doing what I did, which is return instead of emitting the event if I know `ngOnChanges` won't fire. Thank you for sharing your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the intention of Angular and its something you should try to work with rather than *against*.  [Change detection works by components detecting changes in its template bindings and propagating them down the component tree.](https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c) If you can design your application in such a way that you are relying on the immutability of components inputs', you can control this manually by setting `@Component({changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush})` which will test references to determine whether to continue change detection on children components.

So, that said, my experience is that wrappers of 3rd party plugins may not efficiently handle and take advantage of this type of strategy appropriately.  You should attempt to use knowledge of the above, together with good design choices like the separation of concerns of [presentation vs container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) to leverage the detection strategy to achieve good performance.

You can also pass `changes: SimpleChanges` to `ngOnInit(changes: SimpleChanges)` and inspect the object to learn more about your data flow.

Comment: 1 - The input is a primitive here, so the change detection strategy wouldn't make a difference right? 2 - Angular 1 did not cause a re-render after using `ngModelController` to update the parent model with `$setViewValue`, which made sense to me because if a DOM change causes you to update your parent model, you shouldn't then re-render the DOM. If `ngModel` behaves the same way in Angular 2 (haven't checked yet), then maybe using it is the way to work with Angular instead of against it in this particular scenario. 3 - Thanks for the tip about `SimpleChanges`!

Comment: The question really is what about the change propagating from the parent is undesirable? Does it have nothing to do with the third party library?

Comment: If the unnecessary re-render is not expensive it's not really an issue. Like let's say the child component wraps a text box instead of a third party plugin. Someone types into the text box -> child component updates the parent component -> ngOnChanges fires in the child component -> text box is updated with the same text it already had (not so bad). But if instead of a text box it's something like a third party charting library, the re-render may involve expensive calculations or animations.

Comment: @JSF, [you might want to read that](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Comment: Thanks.  Good resource too but doesn't change my answer very much.  Since a 'view' is still associated with each component the general assertion that change detection works via checking a components template references is still true.  Certainly provides a much more thorough explanation though

Comment: @FrankModica right. Certainly want to avoid expensive re-renders. So, when `ngOnChanges` fires, Angular thinks something your child component is using must be updated.  And so you have determined this is an incorrect assumption, in this case?

Comment: Exactly. Any time user interaction puts the DOM in a new state (like typing in a text box), the child component doesn't need to touch the DOM after it updates the parent component, because the DOM is already correct. This situation occurs with most form elements, which is probably why Angular 1 did not call `$render` after `$setViewValue` updates a model. But using `ngModelController` in Angular 1 for custom non-form elements always felt odd. Since using `ngModel` for custom components in Angular 2+ seems a bit more involved, I wanted to see if this is really the way to go.